Determinant of a real and a complex matrix
Let $\mathbf{\Sigma_C}\in\mathbb{C}^n$ be a positive definite matrix. Can we construct a positive definite real symmetric matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma_R}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, such that, for all $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $$|\mathbf{I}_n-\mathbf{\Sigma_C T}|=|\mathbf{I}_n-\mathbf{\Sigma_R T}|$$ where $\mathbf{T}=\operatorname{diag}(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n)$?
The statement holds for $n=2$. In fact, we can write $$\mathbf{\Sigma_C}=\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1^2 &\rho^*\sigma_1\sigma_2\\
\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 &\sigma_2^2\end{bmatrix},$$ with $|\rho|<1$. In this case, we can choose  $$\mathbf{\Sigma_R}=\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1^2 &|\rho|\sigma_1\sigma_2\\
|\rho|\sigma_1\sigma_2 &\sigma_2^2\end{bmatrix}.$$

This is not always possible if $n>2$.
For convenience, I will write $R$ and $C$ for $\Sigma_R$ and $\Sigma_C$. If we put $T=\frac1xD$ where $x$ is a nonzero real number and $D$ is a real diagonal matrix, the given condition implies that $\det(xI-CD)=\det(xI-RD)$. Since both sides are polynomials in $x$, by the identity theorem, we must have $\det(xI-CD)=\det(xI-RD)$ for all $x\in\mathbb C$. Hence $CD$ and $RD$ must have the same eigenvalues for all real diagonal matrices $D$.
So, if we put $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,0,\ldots,0)$, we obtain $c_{11}=r_{11}$. Similarly, $c_{ii}=r_{ii}$ for other indices $i$. Therefore $C$ and $R$ have the same diagonal. Next, if we put $D=I_2\oplus0$, we see that the leading principal $2\times2$ submatrices of $C$ and $R$ must have the same eigenvalues. So, the two minors are the same. Since $C$ and $R$ already have the same diagonal, we must have $r_{12}=\pm|c_{12}|$. Similarly, we have $r_{ij}=\pm|c_{ij}|$ whenever $i\ne j$.
Now consider
$$
C=\pmatrix{2&1&1\\ 1&2&-i\\ 1&i&2}\oplus I_{n-3}.
$$
It is Hermitian and its spectrum is $\{2,\,2+\sqrt{3},\,2-\sqrt{3},\,1,\ldots,1\}$. Hence $C$ is positive definite. From our previous discussion, if the desired $R$ exists, we must have
$$
R=\pmatrix{2&x&y\\ x&2&z\\ y&z&2}\oplus I_{n-3}
$$
for some $x,y,z\in\{1,-1\}$. Hence $\det(R)=2+2xyz\ne2\det(C)$. This is a contradiction as $C$ and $R$ must have the same eigenvalues and hence also the same determinant.

Thank you very much.
